# android createScaledBitmap getHeight() error

Tags: android

on Android, i try to scale an image,and to save it in file in order to able other ajustment on it.
so i wrote this code but with issue:

```
public String ScaledRatioImage(String imageA, float ratio) {
        
    imageA = imageA == null ? "" : imageA;
        
        Bitmap bitmapA=loadImage(imageA);
        int h=bitmapA.getHeight();
        int w=bitmapA.getWidth();
        int nh=(int)((float)h*ratio);
        int nw=(int)((float)w*ratio);
        Bitmap bitmap=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap (bitmapA,nw,nh,true);
        
        String fileSaved= saveBitmap(bitmap,form.getExternalFilesDir("ImgChanged").getAbsolutePath()+"/tmp.png");
        
        return fileSaved ;//image.getAbsolutePath();




private Bitmap loadImage(String path){
        Bitmap bitmapA;
        try { // load the input bitmaps from Assets
            bitmapA = MediaUtil.getBitmapDrawable(container.$form(), path).getBitmap();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            Log.e("Image", "Unable to load ");
            return null;
        }
        return bitmapA;
        
    }
        



  private String saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, String path) {
        File file = null;
        String reponse="vide";
        if (bitmap != null) {
            file = new File(path);
            
            try {
                FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
                try {
                    outputStream = new FileOutputStream(path); //here is set your file path where you want to save or also here you can set file object directly

                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream); // bitmap is your Bitmap instance, if you want to compress it you can compress reduce percentage
                    // PNG is a lossless format, the compression factor (100) is ignored
                    reponse=file.toString();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    reponse="erreur";
                } finally {
                    try {
                        if (outputStream != null) {
                            outputStream.close();
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        //e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                reponse="erreur 2";
            }
        }else{reponse="null";}
        return reponse;
    }
    


    public int Width(String image) {
        Bitmap bitmap=loadImage(image);
        int val=bitmap.getWidth();
        return val;
    }
    

    
    public int Height(tring image) {
        Bitmap bitmap=loadImage(image);
        int val=bitmap.getHeight();
        return val;
    }
```

My problem is:

when i use "ScaledRatioImage" i can see the scaled file in file explorer,
but if i try to load this modified image and use "Width",
i get an error:"Attempt to invoke virtual method.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth() on a null object reference" !

I tried to use "Width" on a non scaled image and then no problem i got Width image...

it seems scaled image is not well define, even if i can open it without any problem in Android standard apps...

wher is th problem ?

Comment: NullPointerException not mentioned.

Comment: Note that the problem exists even if i use  ratio=1 in ScaledRatioImage !

Comment: "NullPointerException not mentioned" sorry i don(t undersand what you said blackapps !

Comment: Your loadImage() function can return null. But you are not checking for null and blindly call null.getWidth().